# how to include isolation level in psql function

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, isolation-level

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createNewOrder(userID text,currency text,orderAmount integer,price integer,isSell boolean,fast boolean) RETURNS integer AS $$
    DECLARE 
    asset record;
    newBalance integer;
    pairKey text;
    begin SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ READ write;
    --get user asset :
    select into asset getUserAssetEntity(userID);
    --check if asset not found :
    if not found then 
    rollback;
    return 101;
    end if;

    pairKey= asset.currency+"_payable" ;
    --check if asset is enoughf : 
    if pairKey >= orderAmount then 
    --create order  
    insert into public.order (pair,amount,price,remain,cdate,sell,cancel,fast,traderid,isactive,status)
    values (currency,orderAmount,price,orderAmount,NOW(),isSell,false,userID,true,"alive");

    --calculate new Balance :

    newBalance=asset.asset.pairKey - orderAmount;

    --update user asset :
    update public.asset set asset.pairKey = newBalance where id=asset.id;

    commit;
    return 103;

    else 
    rollback;
    return 102;
    end if;

    END; $$ 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

---

I tried to use isolation level in my function and It returns this error:

> error: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL must be called before any query

Comment: you can't control transactions or the isolation level _inside_ a function. You need to do that in the code that _calls_ the function

Comment: thanks,can you give me an example please

Answer (score 0):

first all, you can not include commit or rollback command inside a function in postgresql, you can do it in a procedure from version 11.

what it says @a_horse_with_no_name,  is that you must indicate the isolation level before calling the function in a transaction

for instance:

```
 begin SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ READ write;
 select  your_function_createNewOrder(...);
 commit;--rollback
```

Regards